# Struts2 validation failed when i am using radio, select etc

Tags: java, struts2

i am new to struts2 and i am getting error when i am submitting my form and using validation.

See my struts.xml

```
<action name="alltagpage" class="com.ksh.tags.Initialization">
            <result name="success">/alltagspage.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="submittags" class="com.ksh.tags.TagActionClass">
            <result name="input">/alltagspage.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/tagsresult.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

when i am passing this alltagpage request it is initializing "Initialization" class and initialize content for radiobutton.

```
public class Initialization {

    private List<String> languages;
    private List<KeyValue> genders;

    public Initialization()
    {
        System.out.println("Model COnstructor is called");

        languages = new ArrayList<String>();
        languages.add("English");
        languages.add("Hindi");
        languages.add("Gujarati");

        KeyValue keyValue0 = new KeyValue();
        keyValue0.setKey(0);
        keyValue0.setValue("Male");

        KeyValue keyValue1 = new KeyValue();
        keyValue1.setKey(1);
        keyValue1.setValue("Female");

        KeyValue keyValue2 = new KeyValue();
        keyValue2.setKey(2);
        keyValue2.setValue("Unknown");

        genders = new ArrayList<KeyValue>();
        genders.add(keyValue0);
        genders.add(keyValue1);
        genders.add(keyValue2);
    }
    getters and setters..

    public String execute()
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

and following is my Class that will called when i will submit form.

```
public class TagActionClass extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Model> {

    Initialization initialization = new Initialization();
    Model model = new Model();

    public String execute()
    {
        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    public Model getModel() 
    {
        return model;
    } 


    public void validate()
    {
        System.out.println("Kshitij :"+ getModel().getTextfield());

        System.out.println("Kshitij :"+ getModel().getSelectedlanguage());

        System.out.println("Kshitij :"+ getModel().getSelectedgender());

        if(getModel().getTextfield() == null || getModel().getTextfield().isEmpty())
        {
            addActionError("Text Field is empty");
        }
    }
}
```

and it is firing following error when i am submitting form with empty username. I know why this is happening. i need solution.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'radio', field 'list', name 'selectedlanguage': The requested list key 'languages' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:534)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:159)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the first and most common problem, in my opinion, with struts2 validation.

When the validation fails, struts2 redirects to your "input" result (defined in your "struts.xml") and it WON'T execute any of your action methods. If the input is a JSP, it will try to render that JSP...
You didnt include yor JSP but it probably contains radio, select or other tags that expect to recieve a collection from your action to initialize them, but when validation fails they won't get anything, so that's the error.

Solution: You need some method in your action that creates the needed collections or other params that you always need in your jsp. You could do that in your action constructor, which will be called, even if fails validation, but it's a dirty solution. The good solution is to use the Preparable interceptor (included in the DefaultStack of Struts2 interceptor).
Then you will have a prepare() method that will be called always, even if validation fails.

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/prepare-interceptor.html